# I have PHP string, need to get values in a variable as mentioned

Tags: php, string, get, integer

I have PHP string in the below format,
`$msg=Temp:29.6 C  RH:57 %  WD:29 Deg  WS: 0.6 Kts  SLP:1005.4 hPa  Rain:0.0  mm`

My questions is  how to get values in variable?

Answer (score 0):

If your string exist in variable $temp

e.g.
*$temp = '$msg=Temp:29.6 C RH:57 % WD:29 Deg WS: 0.6 Kts SLP:1005.4 hPa Rain:0.0 mm';*

then
*$msg = str_replace('$msg=', '', $temp);*

will give you the desire output value in $msg variable.

Answer (score 0):

make a new string by deleting the spaces from the value and unit. It should be look like below.

```
$msg=Temp:29.6C RH:57% WD:29Deg WS:0.6Kts SLP:1005.4hPa Rain:0.0mm
```

Explode the string using explode() function

```
       $msgarray = explode(" ", $msg);
  it will return $msgarray[0]=Temp:29.6C and so on...

for($i=0;$1<count(&msgarray);i++
{
 $temp = explode(":", $msgarray[i]);
 $key = $temp[0];
 $value = $temp[1];
 $output[key] = $value;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
```

$output array will contain the keys and values associated with that keys. it will be an associative array.$output array will be like below

```
$output['Temp'] = 29.6C
$output['RH'] = 57%
$output['WD'] = 29Deg
$output['WS'] =0.6Kts
$output['SPL'] =1005.4hPa
$output['Rain'] = 0.0mm
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_match_all`:

```
$msg = 'Temp:29.6 C  RH:57 %  WD:29 Deg  WS: 0.6 Kts  SLP:1005.4 hPa  Rain:0.0  mm';

preg_match_all('/([a-z]+):([0-9]+\.?[0-9]+?[\s]{1,2}[a-z%]+)/i', $msg, $matches);

$values = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($values);
echo '</pre>';
```

The result will be a structure as:

```
array(5) {
  ["Temp"]=>
  string(6) "29.6 C"
  ["RH"]=>
  string(4) "57 %"
  ["WD"]=>
  string(6) "29 Deg"
  ["SLP"]=>
  string(10) "1005.4 hPa"
  ["Rain"]=>
  string(7) "0.0  mm"
}
```